# initialise a variable with a network call in a construtor in Dart

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm not really sure how to construct my constructor for a dart class that will initialise my instance variable. I need to initialise my variable `_desserts` with a network call to firestore on creation of the object

```
class DessertDataSource extends DataTableSource {


  final List<Dessert> _desserts;

  DessertDataSource(this._desserts);



  Future<List<Dessert>> getData() async{
    await Firestore.instance.collection("desserts").getDocuments()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      return snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) =>{
        _desserts.add(Dessert.fromSnapshot(doc))
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructors in Dart cannot be asynchronous.

If you want to create an object asynchronously, make a static function for it instead:

```dart
class DessertDataSource extends DataTableSource {
  final List<Dessert> _desserts;
  DessertDataSource._(this._desserts);

  static Future<DessertDataSource> create() async {
    var snapshot = 
        await Firestore.instance.collection("desserts").getDocuments();
    return DessertDataSource._(
        [for (var doc in snapshot.documents) Dessert.fromSnapshot(doc)]);
  }
}
```

Then you can call it as `await DessertDataSource.create()`.

Comment: thanks, Can't compile: "snapshot" `The type QuerySnapshot used in the for loop must implement iterable.`

Comment: Ack, forgot a `.documents`. Added now. I'm assuming that snapshot.documents is iterable since it has a `forEach`.